# Distributed Solr: different number of results each time

Tags: solr, distributed

I'm using **faceted search** in SolrCloud to get some statistics on my corpus. The query is something like this:

http://master-node:8983/solr/select?q=field1:value1&distrib=true&facet=true&facet.field=field1&facet.limit=50000&rows=0&fq=field2:value2

However, in production with high number of documents, shared between ~5 machines, master node returns different number of results each time. (Each slave by itself returns correct value).

I expected it is because of small timeout for shards, so I added following params to the search request handler in `solr/conf/solrconfig.xml`:

```
<int name="shard-socket-timeout">10000</int>
<int name="shard-connection-timeout">10000</int>
```

but it didn't help.

Am I missing some **configuration** or is it just a **bug**? If it's a bug, how can I overcome it (except manual tracking of every slave)?

Comment: I posted workaround [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Distributed-Solr-different-number-of-results-each-time-td3550284.html).